# printf causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) warning and freezes at runtime

Tags: c, printf, i386

I have a function composed of 3 nested for loops and an if statement, inside it i have:

```
int buffsize = valuex*3;
    //int buffsize = (LEDS+1)*3;
    char buffer[buffsize];
    init_buf(buffer, buffsize);
    // while(counter <= linecount){

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    char *bufpointer=buffer;

    for (x=0; x<=valuex; x++) {

        for (y=0;y<=LEDS; y++) {

            for (int i=0; i<=linecount; i++) {

                if (pixels[i].y==y) {

                    snprintf(bufpointer+=strlen(bufpointer), buffsize, "%s%d%d%d",buffer, pixels[i].r,pixels[i].g, pixels[i].b );
                    printf("buffer contents: %s\n",buffer);


                }

            }
         printf("buffer contents: %s\n",buffer);  //placed for debugging
        }

    }



    /**************** buffer initialiser ********************/

    void init_buf(char *buf, size_t size){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        buf[i] = '0'; // int to char conversion
     }
    }
```

with bufpointer being a pointer to char array buffer.

I am trying to read integer values from the pixels[] struct and add them all to a single buffer.

my problem is that I get a warning at the printf function stating: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

during runtime the program runs till the printf statement and freezes there

Comment: You'll need to add more of your code (prior to the call to `snprintf`), so we can see how you're allocating the buffer and details about the type oft bufpointer and how it's being used. These two lines out of context are insufficient, but my guess is that you're either accessing memory you haven't allocated or running off the end of the buffer somewhere.

Comment: I agree with Ken.  I'd for example be interested to know how the buffer pointed to is initialised, and if it's made sure that there's always a null terminated string there. Also, do you make sure that buffsize is decreased to the remaining space left when bufpointer is increased ?

Comment: I added more code now, I am not sure how to decrease the value of buffsize after every iteration, I also tried running the function using sprint as it does not require buffsize as an argument but that failed with the exact same problem

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're accessing memory past the end of one of your arrays.

The `bufpointer+=strlen(bufpointer)` combined with `buffsize` looks suspicious.  I assume you're using `bufpointer` to concatentate several strings into a single buffer by making each `snprintf` call start writing at the null byte left by the previous call.  If that's the case, the second argument to `snprintf` should be the amount of space *remaining* in the buffer, not the *total* size of the buffer.  For example, if you have a buffer with room for 100 characters, and the first `snprintf` call writes ten, then for the second call the size limit should be 90, not 100.

You haven't posted code enough code to show how `bufpointer` and `buffsize` are initialized and whether they're altered by the loop, so it's not clear that this is the cause of your problem, but I suspect that it is.

Comment: bufpointer and buffsize are constants that are initialised before any of the loops starts, so from what you just said my code is wrong in the sense that buffsize does not adjust for space remaining, how can I do that?

Comment: use a temprary size_t sz=strlen(bufpointer); just before snprintf(), where you can then use bufpointer+=sz and buffsize-=sz

Comment: When you add the length of the prior string to `bufpointer`, you also need to subtract that same number from `buffsize`.  (Note that `snprintf` returns the number of characters that it wrote; you can use that instead of calling `strlen`.)